# No static method deleteRecursively(Ljava/io/File;) in androidTest when enabling proguard

Tags: java, android, kotlin, proguard

I am trying to enable proguard on my android tests. But I am facing a strange problem:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method deleteRecursively(Ljava/io/File;)Z in class Lkotlin/io/FilesKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'kotlin.io.FilesKt' appears in /data/app/org.walleth.offline-BAciL8erjxU-sHGjQe6uQg==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
at org.ligi.trulesk.RulesKt.doBefore(Rules.kt:82)
at org.ligi.trulesk.RulesKt.access$doBefore(Rules.kt:1)
at org.ligi.trulesk.TruleskIntentRule.beforeActivityLaunched(Rules.kt:58)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.launchActivity(ActivityTestRule.java:351)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:525)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:384)
at org.ligi.trulesk.AppReplacingRunnerBase.onStart(AppReplacingRunnerBase.kt:19)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2145)
```

`Proguard` on the release build works - not sure why it is so aggressive on android tests. Ideally the instrumentation classes would not be removed at all.

Answer (score 3):

I think core issue is that `androidTest` is a different compilation unit. `app/src/androidTest` is assembled into `app-debug-androidTest.apk` while `app/src/main` is assembled into `app-debug.apk`. And so Proguard during `assembleDebug` neither see no includes `app/src/androidTest` into building "tree shaking" usage graph because it is not available on the classpath. Practically, it means that application code which is referenced in tests only is being stipped out.

This topic correlates with "Should I change visibility from private to public just for the test access?" dilema. Depending on what kind of tests you are writing you may consider to:

- Always keep application extra entry points (used by tests) in shippable to users `release.apk`
- Compile main apk differently when running the test and again accept the risk of shipping to users not exactly the same code which is being run by test

Unfortunately, I don't know any auto-magic solution at the moment (similar to `all-open` plugin). But it is possible to resolve missing methods issue in a case-by-case way.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt', 'proguard-project-ext.txt'
        testProguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-test-project.txt'
    }
}
```

- `proguard-project.txt` - configuration for `app/src/main` and it's `implementation` dependencies
- `proguard-project-ext.txt` - configuration for `app/src/main` which contains `-keep` instructions for every method/field used in tests only which was "falsely" removed by proguard. I prefer to keep it separately, to conditionally remove when publishing to google play
- `proguard-test-project.txt` - configuration for `app/src/androidTest` and it's `androidTestImplementation` dependencies. Typically contains `-dontwarn net.bytebuddy.**` and etc. Although note, that test apk doesn't support multidex so it is possible to hit `65k` limit method by including too many dependencies.

Check [android/platform/tools/base/studio-master-dev/./build-system/integration-test/test-projects/minify](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/integration-test/test-projects/minify) for the implementation reference.

Answer (score 0):

`test` builds are <strike>by default</strike> always `debug` builds - even when setting a `testBuildType`, this has to have config `initWith debug`, which hints for a whole other mis-configuration. sorry for not providing the expected answer, but this mis-configuration is based upon a certain  mis-conception. I'd suggest to disable the obfuscation, because it's rather pointless in this case, because this package won't ever be distributed. it might not even be possible to define ProGuard rules for the test application (which is a package on it's own). this behavior is "by design", caused by working against the test framework... because the test application will not know about the class/method obfuscation mapping of the other one  application package - and therefore the chances are rather slim, that this could ever work out.

Firebase Test Lab  [Robo UX Test](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/robo-ux-test) is the most similar to what is effectivly being demanded.

Comment: But I want it to be enabled - e.g. to catch errors in the UI tests rather than manual testing or even at the user

Comment: @ligi extended my answer with a) an explanation why it cannot work and b) an alternative.

Comment: thanks - but sorry I do not think the explanation is correct and b is not an alternative for me